# Socket IO cannot receive message after joining room

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io, react-redux

I'm building an app that allows you to join games and then receive updates from other players in the game. Before adding the rooms functionality the sockets worked fine, but now clients don't receive messages broadcast to their respective rooms.

Server Code:

```
io.on('connection', client => {
      // JOIN GAME
      client.on('join-game', ({gameId, playerId}) => {
        console.log(gameId)
        client.join('new-room', () => {
          io.sockets.in('new-room').emit('player-joined-game', 'Is this thing on?);
        })
    });
```

Client Code:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  const socket = socketIOClient('localhost:5000');
  socket.on('player-joined-game', game => {
    console.log(game)
  })
}
```

The server receives the message, but the client does not print 'Is this thing on?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by creating a new socket instance each time I sent the 'join room' message from client to server. This meant each time I was joining a room, I was adding a new socket to the room. This was solved by moving my client socket declaration to a constants file and pulling that in for all of my socketIO usages.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your client might have not joined any game since your client haven't emitted "join-game" message.
Plus,
you have missed 'http://' on your url string.

Can you try following on your client side:

```js
componentDidMount = () => {
  const socket = socketIOClient('http://localhost:5000');
  socket.on('player-joined-game', game => {
    console.log(game)
  });
  socket.emit('join-game',{gameId:'game1',playerId:'player1'});
}
```

Comment: Hey @dropyourcoffee, thanks for the response! As I said, client code worked correctly when I was not using rooms, so I don't think its the url that is the issue. The 'join-game'  message is being emitted by a redux action and is being correctly received in the server. The message emitted here `io.sockets.in('new-room').emit('player-joined-game', 'Is this thing on?);` is not being received in the client.

Comment: Okay. Maybe the cause was
```js
client.join('new-room', () => {
          io.in('new-room').emit('player-joined-game', 'Is this thing on?);
        })
```
instead of,
```js
client.join('new-room', () => {
          io.sockets.in('new-room').emit('player-joined-game', 'Is this thing on?);
        })
```
on server side??

Comment: Yeah, I've seen both ways and I tried both, but neither worked!

Comment: I am not 100% sure since I don't know how you have implemented your redux action, but maybe it worths doubting if the component initially mounts before the redux action is triggered.

Comment: I also tried moving all of the code inside `render` to no avail :(

Comment: Okay final try..
how about putting 
```js
io.socket.in('new-room')
``` out of 
```js
client.join()
```
 ?? (putting broadcast part beneath join(), not as a callback)

Comment: Literally just tried this 
`client.join('new-room', () => {
      io.in('new-room').emit('player-joined-game', 'Is this thing on?');
      io.sockets.in('new-room').emit('player-joined-game', 'Is this thing on?');
    })
    io.in('new-room').emit('player-joined-game', 'Is this thing on?');
    io.sockets.in('new-room').emit('player-joined-game', 'Is this thing on?');`
and it didn't work!